# CSS3 Animation Rotate, removing animate property makes the animation revert back to its origin position

Tags: css, css-animations

When I'm rotating a graphic with CSS3 using the code below (this is just the webkit version but have the other browser specific versions in my style sheet).

```
.bottomSmallCogStopAnimating  {
   -webkit-animation-name: rotate;
   -webkit-animation-duration: 5000ms;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
}
```

I'm using jQuery to add this css class to stop the animation by removing the animation name.

```
.stopAnimating {
  -moz-animation: none;
  -webkit-animation: none;
  animation: none;
}
```

Removing this property appears to reset the graphic back to its pre rotated state, so what I'm seeing is the graphic pop back to its original rotation which looks pretty bad.

Is there a way to stop this from happening, so the browser will remember its last position and stop animating at this point?

Cheers,
Stefan

Comment: I stand to be corrected, but without JavaScript, this is not easily possible. There's a possibility, perhaps, with `data-` attributes.

Comment: CSS animations are not CSS transitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the animation from css, or putting it to "none", will revert to the initial state.
You could just pause it using:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('bottomSmallCogStopAnimating')[0].webkitAnimationPlayState = 'paused'
```

Or add a class name:

```
.stopAnimating {
-webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
}
```

I am not really sure what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thank you I didn't know this property existed, this has solved the problem without having to use other JS or jQuery animation libraries which didn't have very good control on multiple elements. But basically I have an animation of cogs which animate when triggered by the browser's scroll event.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to keep the 100% state when the animation finishes, right? So the animation animates from 0% to 100% and then on 100% it stays like that, if that's what you're trying to do, then you actually want to add this:

```
-webkit-animation-fill-mode:forwards;
```

No js required, this will keep the 100% state when the animation finishes.

Comment: Hey android.nick,

In this instance just pausing the animation was sufficient. As my animation responded to the user scrolling the page I needed to use JS/jQuery to trigger the animation playing and pausing by removing or adding a css class to a graphic. But it's useful to know that I can manipulate the direction of the animation this will come in handy for future projects.

many thanks